# Pandas: How can I create a new dataframe from only certain columns?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a csv file with measurements and I want to create a new csv file with the hourly averages and standard deviations. But only for certain columns.

Example:

csv1:

```
YY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS    |     Acceleration  |        Lumx     |    Pressure
2015-12-07 20:51:06:608  |        22.7       |        32.3     |     10
2015-12-07 20:51:07:609  |        22.5       |        47.7     |     15
```

to csv 2 (only for the pressure and acceleration):

```
 YY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS       | Acceleration avg  |   Pressure avg
    2015-12-07 20:00:00:000  |        22.6       |        12.5     
    2015-12-07 21:00:00:000  |        ....       |        ....
```

Now I have an idea how to calculate the averages, but I'm having trouble creating a smaller `dataframe` that contains the calculations for a few columns. How can I do that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can make a smaller DataFrame like below:

```py
csv2 = csv1[['Acceleration', 'Pressure']].copy()
```

Then you can handle `csv2`, which only has the columns you want. (You said you have an idea about avg calculation.)
FYI, `.copy()` could be omitted if you are sure about [view versus copy](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy).

Comment: But how can I copy straight from the dataframe after the calculations?

Comment: @RonMaor You can assign the result like `csv2=pd.DataFrame(); csv2['Acceleration Avg'] = csv1[['Acceleration', 'Pressure']].copy().apply(your_function)` and so on.

Answer (score 6):

```
csv2 = csv1.loc[:, ['Acceleration', 'Pressure']]
```

- `.loc[]` helps keep the subsetting operation explicit and consistent.
- `.loc[]` always returns a copy so the original dataframe is never modified.

(for further discussion and great examples of the different `view vs. copy` alternatives please see: [Pandas: Knowing when an operation affects the original dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48173980/pandas-knowing-when-an-operation-affects-the-original-dataframe))

Comment: I use this style too but the selected answer works as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your average method can go in place of **"method_to_obtain_avg"** and then you can obtain a subset as below:

```
csv2 = csv1.method_to_obtain_avg()[["Accelaration", "Pressure"]]
```