# Python Pandas, Try to update cell value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've 2 dataframe, both with a column date:
I need to set in **first dataframe** the value of specific column found in the **second dataframe**,
So in first of all I find the correct row of first dataframe with:

```
id_row = int(dataset.loc[dataset["time"] == str(searchs.index[x])].index[0]) #example: 910
```

and then I want to update the value of column `['search_volume']` at this row: **910**
I will do this with:

```
dataset['search_volume'][id_row] = searchs[kw_list[0]][x]
```

but I get back this error:

```
/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:8: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
```

my full code is, but not working and nothing is updated.

```
for x in range(len(searchs)):
    id_row = int(dataset.loc[dataset["time"] == str(searchs.index[x])].index[0])
    dataset['search_volume'][id_row] = searchs[kw_list[0]][x]
```

It work fine if I test manually the update with:

```
dataset['search_volume'][910] = searchs[kw_list[0]][47]
```

What's append?!

Answer (score 0):

Use `.loc`:

```py
dataset.loc[910, 'search_volume'] = searchs.loc[47, kw_list[0]]
```

For more info about the error message, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48173980/pandas-knowing-when-an-operation-affects-the-original-dataframe)

Also, there are way more efficient methods for doing this. As a rule of thumb, if you are looping over a dataframe, you are generally doing something wrong. Some potential solutions: `pd.DataFrame.join`, `pd.merge`, masking, `pd.DataFrame.where`, etc.