# pandas change dataset value of a specific row using loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to programming, I'm working on a python project using pandas
I wanted to change values of each row of a dataset using .loc, but it seems like it won't work, the idea is to make a row take EOL value if the row is equal to 0, the code doesn't bring an error, but my dataset is unchanged after the iterations. Here is the code:

```
for machines in telemetry_days['machineID']:
EOL = 365
i = 0

for row in telemetry_days['failure_comp1'].loc[(telemetry_days['machineID'] == machines)]:
    
    if (row != 0):
        EOL = row
      
    elif (row == 0):
        telemetry_days['failure_comp1'].loc[(telemetry_days['machineID'] == machines)].iloc[i] = EOL
    i = i + 1
```

I think it's because i'm using .iloc so it won't change the value of 'failure_comp1' in the dataset. But I can't figure out how to get a specific row from .loc without using .iloc., if anyone as any suggestions I'd be very grateful, thanks
Here is the structure of the whole dataset (don't mind the NaNs):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjV9c.png)
Here is what i have for example (for one 'machine'):

```
index failure_comp1
67    0
254   150
568   0
850   0
998   345
```

I want it to become this:

```
index failure_comp1
67    365
254   150
568   150
850   150
998 345
```

It's a time series dataset and i want to label each component of machines with it's End Of Life time (number of days), i've already got it labeled at the date where it fails, but I want to have it labeled for each row of that specific component.

Comment: Are you just wanting to replace any non 0 with 365 in the `'failure_comp1'` column?

Comment: provide a sample data set (just a few rows) and your desired output. I don't quite understand what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Do you __need__ to use .loc and/or .iloc?

Comment: I edited my post, and no I don't need to use loc or iloc, i tried using .at() but I couldn't figure out a way either, so any way to do it is fine.

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48173980/pandas-knowing-when-an-operation-affects-the-original-dataframe) and you'll know

Comment: so the first 0 needs to be 365. Then all sequential 0s what ever the previous non-zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I wouldn't iterate through the rows (although you could if you want, I'll show that solution too). But what I would do is use a `.groupby('macineID')`. 1) Then convert all the 0s to nan. 2) forward fill the nans. 3) this will leave the first 0 as a nan, so finally fillna with 365.

Given as a sample data set:

```
import pandas as pd

telemetry_days = pd.DataFrame({
    'machineID':['11','22','33','44','11','22','33','44','11','22','33','44','11','22','33','44','11','22','33','44'],
    'failure_comp1':[0,2,45,0, 
                     150,150,232,0, 
                     0, 0, 0, 0, 
                     0, 12, 0, 0,
                     345, 12, 0, 0]})
```

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


telemetry_days['failure_comp1'] = telemetry_days['failure_comp1'].replace(0, np.nan)
telemetry_days['failure_comp1'] = telemetry_days.groupby('machineID', as_index=False)['failure_comp1'].ffill().fillna(365)
```

**If you want to use the .loc or .iloc:**

Here's how I would do it. I would loop through each unique machineID, filter the dataframe to get just those machines, then iterrate through that sub-group. I also would not hard code the `i` (index). `.iteritems()` and or `iterrows()` will returns the index value for you, so just use that.

```
for machines in telemetry_days['machineID'].unique():
    EOL = 365
   
    for i, row in telemetry_days[telemetry_days['machineID'] == machines]['failure_comp1'].iteritems():
        
        if (row != 0):
            EOL = row
          
        elif (row == 0):
            telemetry_days['failure_comp1'].iloc[i] = EOL
```