# Why does .copy() fail to make a deep copy when the elements of the original dataframe are lists?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

tl;dr: Operations on a dataframe create using .copy() do not affect the original dataframe when its elements are of a certain type, but they do when the elements are list.

Note that this is distinct from other questions already asked. Namely: while other answers provide an explanation for how copies work (especially shallow vs deep copies), this is specifically about why the behavior appears to be inconsistent.

---

## Cases where Pandas behaves as expected

##### Creating the new dataframe by assignment

[I have understood that under some conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48173980/pandas-knowing-when-an-operation-affects-the-original-dataframe), creating a new variable `foo` using an existing pandas dataframe `bar` can mean that operations on `foo` creates changes in `bar` as well. Hence:

```
foo = pd.DataFrame({'A':['one','two','three'],'B':['apple','banana','grape'],'C':['cat','zebra','donkey']})  
bar = foo
bar['A'] = ['four','five','six']
```

will give `foo['A'] = ['four','five','six']`.

##### Using .copy() and performing operations on columns

Fair enough. We spend no more than a minute searching to find that what you really need to do is:

```
foo = pd.DataFrame({'A':['one','two','three'],'B':['apple','banana','grape'],'C':['cat','zebra','donkey']})
bar = foo.copy()   
bar['A'] = ['four','five','six']
```

and faithfully enough, this gives `foo['A'] = ['one','two','three']`.

##### Using .copy() and performing operations on single elements

Likewise, performing an operation on just one element in `foo` leaves `bar` unaffected as desired:

```
foo = pd.DataFrame({'A':['one','two','three'],'B':['apple','banana','grape'],'C':['cat','zebra','donkey']})
bar = foo.copy()   
bar['A'][0] = 'four'
```

which as expected/desired gives `foo['A']=['one','two','three']`.

## Where things go wrong: Using .copy() and forming operations on single elements that are lists

Here comes the twist:

```
foo = pd.DataFrame({'A':[['one','two','three'],['four','five','six'],['seven','eight','nine']]})
bar = foo.copy()   
bar['A'][0][0] = 'apple'
```

gives `foo['A'][0] = ['apple','two','three']`.

Why does this happen? What is the correct way to make a copy of the original dataframe if I don't want operations on the new dataframe to affect the original dataframe when the elements of the dataframe are lists?

Comment: From my understanding, the 2nd and 3rd cases create new objects in memory. By contrast, the 4th is modifies an object in memory, which is why the modification is reflected in both DataFrames.Note that my question is distinct from others already asked. What is not included in the threads I linked to (but which is noted in other threads here) is that .copy() creates a shallow copy--a good (?) solution is to explicitly make a deep copy. But this concerns seemingly inconsistent behavior in the context of shallow copies. If anyone know if my interpretation is wrong, please leave a note!