# Does that make sense to make a list of dataframes and analyze the list elements pair wise?

Tags: python, dataframe, influxdb-python

I am querying several signals from InfluxDB to the Pandas dataframe every 5 minutes. If these signals meet a specific condition, I add the dataframes to the list. Then I want to take dataframes pair wise and perform a calculation on them.

```
df_list = data_pool() # data_pool() returns list of dataframes
for i in range(len(df_list)-1):
    for j in range(i+1, len(df_list)):
        calc(df_list[i], df_list[j])
```

In the `calc()`, I am manipulating the timestamps data. This logic work for `df_list[0]` and `df_list[1]`, but for the next loop because `df_list[0]` is already manipulated, the `calc()` cannot be performed between `df_list[0]` and other dataframes.

How should I tackle this issue?
Is generally adding pandas dataframe to a list a good idea?

I appreciate any idea or help.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a long time to find where the issue came from. The problem is that pandas dataframe got updated inside `calc()` function and affected the original one. To tackle this problem, I made a copy of dataframe inside the `calc()` function. I suggest reading this [Pandas: Knowing when an operation affects the original dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48173980/pandas-knowing-when-an-operation-affects-the-original-dataframe).